# How often can spells be cast from a Rod of Alertness?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

One of the features of the [Rod of Alertness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-alertness) allows the wielder to cast a number of spells:

> While holding the rod, you can use an action to cast one of the following spells from it: *detect evil and good*, *detect magic*, *detect poison and disease*, or *see invisibility*.

Unlike many other magic items that can be used to cast spells, there is no further text indicating how often these spells can be used. **Does the lack of any stated limit mean that these spells can be cast from the rod any number of times, effectively turning them into cantrips for the wielder of the rod?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, the spells have unlimited usage

As there is nothing in the description that indicates otherwise, the rod allows you to cast these spells as many times as you want using one action each time a spell is cast.

This rod does require attunement so it counts as one of your 3 attuned items. Also you must hold it in your hand to use it which means you can't hold something else in that hand. Three of the four spells require concentration to use (thanks to V2blast for pointing this out), and all are low-level and do not cause damage, 3 first level and one second level spell. So this isn't an incredibly powerful feature, but certainly a nice one for additional perception based spells for your character.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that they're all basically utility spells that mainly see use outside of combat; they don't do any damage or really have game-breaking effects, and all but *see invisibility* require concentration (a cost of a different sort).

Comment: @v2blast good points, added more detail to the answer.